# Wire up button click events after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table with various rows, each has a delete button with a class.

On the `DocumentReady` event I wire up all buttons with this class to handle the `click` event.

On the `click` event, it does a `jQuery` `POST` which deletes data from the database and returns the table with the removed row.

If I go to click another delete button it doesn't do anything as if the `click` event is not wired up.  I have tried wiring it up in the `OnSuccess` event as well as `DocumentReady` but nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do post your `jQuery` code responsible for that whole logic.  Just as a shot in the dark I'd suggest you'll have to use:

```
$(".button").live("click",function(){...})
```

instead of

```
$(".button").click(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the live binding function in jquery to be able to bind to all specified elements at any time of creation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are removing the entire table (with the buttons that have events attached to them) and replacing it with a new table (with new buttons that don't have buttons attached).

You have a couple of options.

1. Just remove the row that you delete - don't replace the entire table
2. Use [event delegation](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/) and put the event handler on the element containing the table
3. Rerun the code that attaches the events every time you rebuild the table

Comment: Limited? I would have thought options 1 and 3 were obvious enough, and I linked out for more detail on option 2.